# Select rows matching calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query to calculate the most common days of the week and hours:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%a') AS wd,
  HOUR(DATE) AS hr,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM 
 users
GROUP BY
  wd, hr
ORDER BY
  cnt DESC
```

Now, I want to select the ID's of all the rows that match `wd = "Fri" AND hr = "9"`

I've tried adding a `WHERE` clause but I couldn't since I can't use `WHERE` on aliases.

Comment: share your table's data and your query you reached till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID
FROM   users
WHERE  DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%a') = 'Fri' AND HOUR(DATE) = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%a') AS wd,
  HOUR(DATE) AS hr,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM users
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%a') = 'Fri'
AND HOUR(DATE) = 9
GROUP BY wd, hr
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

You could also do it using an aliased select, but the performance would *not* be as good, because this way filtering is happening *before* aggregation